# How to get the deselected value with Chosen

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using Chosen jQuery plugin, and I have successfully installed it.
now I want to get the selected or deselected items, here is the docs:

```
http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html
```

It says on change trigger, it sends `select` and `deselect` as parameters, how could I access to those?

for example:

```
$('#days').on('change', function(evt, params) {
    // alert selected val if the users selected new item
    // alert deselected val if the users deselected item
}
```

Thanks

Comment: In your event handler, do `console.log(arguments)` and see what you have available.

Comment: it says `[object Arguments]`

Comment: In what browser? In chrome or firebug, you should be able to expand the object and look through its properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$('#days').on('change', function(evt, params) {
    // can now use params.selected and params.deselected
}`